# possible jquery image slider with vertical thumbnails?

Tags: jquery, slider

I am looking for a jquery slider that incorporates a vertical slider either on the right or left hand side that once clicked shows the larger image that will then be linked to 'x'.

im having a hard time coming across anything that suits my needs.

Does anyone have any ideas or possible links to some resources or github?

[image]

Something in these lines would be perfect but nothing has come up from my search results :(

Comment: Almost every single slider has this! But it's all about the styling of the Slide list =) (Most typically, the `<ul>`)

Comment: really... Im using flexslider atm and this isnt in the docs as long as i know. Would be great to have this installed.

Comment: Are you just looking for a slider with the thumbnails stacked vertically?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11940549/flexslider-2-vertical-thumbnail-navigation

Comment: Yes mate. I have a simple slider from flexslider that pulls a featured image from a different category on each slide. but would like a thumbnail vertically that is clickable to bring the next slide across

Comment: i saw that link before actually and did notice about re assembling the css and js params. I havent tried that as of yet, but thought it was best to see if anyone had an updated approach.

Answer (score 0):

This could give you a good starting point,

http://designm.ag/tutorials/image-rotator-css-jquery/

Comment: thanks, that is what im looking for. Ill try this if i cant get my flexslider to do the same. Thankyou