# flexslider vertical thumbnail carousel

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexslider

I'm trying to create a vertical thumbnails-slider with flexslider, but it very buggy.

After playing with it today, I fix a lot of bugs except one: When sliding up in the carousel (i.e pressing `.flex-next`) it keep sliding three more times after reaching the last image, you can press it three more.

Here's the slider after reaching the last image:

**How the carousel should look**

[image: How the carousel should look]

In that case the top arrow should be unclickable, but I can click it three more times and then the carousel looks like this:

**How the carousel really looks:**

[image: How the carousel really looks]

Here's the code:
HTML

```
<div class="flex-slider-wrapper row">   
    <div class="col-sm-3">   
        <div id="carousel" class="flexslider">   
            <ul class="slides">
                <?php
                if( have_rows('popup_repeater') ):

                    while( have_rows('popup_repeater') ): the_row();
                        $img_url = get_sub_field('popup_add_img');
                        echo "<li><img src= '" . esc_url( $img_url['url'] ) . "'/></li>";
                    endwhile;
                else:
                    echo "";  
                endif;
                ?>   
            </ul>    
        </div><!--#carousel-->    
    </div>   
    <div class="col-sm-9">    
        <div id="slider" class="flexslider">    
            <ul class="slides">   
                <?php
                if( have_rows('popup_repeater') ):

                    while( have_rows('popup_repeater') ): the_row();
                        $img_url = get_sub_field('popup_add_img');
                        echo "<li><img src= '" . esc_url( $img_url['url'] ) . "'/></li>";
                    endwhile;  
                else :
                    echo "";   
                endif;
                ?>    
            </ul>   
        </div><!--#slider-->
    </div>  
</div><!--.flexslider-wrapper-->
```

JS

```
$('.ajax-popup-link-agency').magnificPopup({
    type: 'ajax',
    midClick: true,
    overflowY: "scroll",
    alignTop: true,
    fixedBgPos: true,
    closeMarkup: "<button title='%title%' type='button' class='mfp-close'>button</button>",
    fixedContentPos: false,
    callbacks: {
        ajaxContentAdded: function() {
            $('#carousel').flexslider({
                animation: 'slide',
                direction: direction,
                controlNav: false,
                animationLoop: false,
                itemWidth: 143,
                itemMargin: 2,
                maxItems: 4,
                slideshow: false,
                asNavFor: '#slider'
            });
            $('#slider').flexslider({
                animation: 'slide',
                controlNav: false,
                directionNav: true,
                animationLoop: false,
                slideshow: false,
                sync: '#carousel'
            });
        }
    }
});
```

CSS

```css
#carousel li {
  float: none !important;
  margin-right: auto !important;
  margin-left: auto !important;
}

#carousel .flex-viewport{
  height: 457px;
}

#slider .flex-viewport, #slider .slides {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Note: when I switch and put `.col-sm-9` to to `#carousel` and `col-sm-3` to `#slider`, it doesn't happen.

Will appreciate any help!

Comment: have u solved this ? if yes plz share the same.

Comment: Some great answers have been provided at the [Flexslider 2 vertical thumbnail navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11940549/flexslider-2-vertical-thumbnail-navigation) SO question.